# What is android api level of my project

Tags: android

If the minSdkVersion of my project is 11 then what is the api level of my project? I mean how
to check whether I am working in api version 2, 3 or above? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually keep the project's targetSDK at the same level, and just use a minSDK value.

What this means is that your application will target to build against a certain API, but it will let phones with lesser versions of Android than that API to also run the app. The catch is that you have to make sure you don't make any API calls that don't exist in the older versions of Android.

To change this, go to your AndroidManifest.xml and add the following inside of the xml node:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
```

This would set your minsdk to Android 1.5. Change it 4 for Android 1.6 and so on.

But if you really want to change the TargetSDK, right click on your project --> properties. Then click the Android tab on the left. Then check the box of the target API you want to build against.

List of api level is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history) and example is [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html)

Answer (score 1):

The minSdkVersion attribute only specifies the lowest API level on which your application will run.

If you did not set targetSdk or maxSdkVersion, then your app will run on the api level of the android device (if it is above or equal of minSdkVersion).

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Answer (score 0):

1) Right Click On Project

2) Click on "Properties"

3) Select "Android" from left Tab

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check targetSdkVersion in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
   <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```